# Best practices for storing unchanging keys used in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, constants, performance

I've been searching for any insight into best practices for making sure there is consistency with my keys in a dictionary. The dictionary is used throughout multiple classes, so there is a main class that stores the dictionary for access from each class.

My question really is this: multiple classes access this `Dictionary<string, object>` and the set of keys (about 40 in total) are always the same. Right now I am accessing the values through `dictionary["keyname"]`, but I was wondering if it would be a better practice to use use const strings to store these keys or if there was a more effective way to reduce the chance of introducing errors through misspelling and to make it easier to keep track of the keys. The keys need to be strings or need to be quickly convertible to strings as they are also used in a multipart form for submission to a web service.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would be tempted to use an enumerated type rather than constants.  It will be stored as an ordinal and so will be very fast.

You could then use Enum.GetValue() to convert it to text.

Comment: I had considered this approach before but was concerned about the time it takes to get the string equivalent of the enum type. In the end it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Comment: You could always use another dictionary to lookup the sting value.  That would be quicker and you could also add string values with spaces ie EnumeratedValue could become 'Enumerated Value'.

Comment: Oh I hadn't even thought of that. Makes sense. Thanks for the advice!